# Copy selected lines from one file to another

Tags: python, file, argparse, getopt, copying

I am trying to write a program in python which searches for user specified words in a txt file and copies the selected lines containing that word into another file.

Also the user will have an option to exclude any word.

(e.g Suppose the user searches for the word "exception" and want to exclude the word "abc", then the code will only copy the lines which has "exception" in it but not "abc").

Now all the work will be done from the command prompt.

The input would be:

```
file.py test.txt(input file) test_mod.txt(output file) -e abc(exclude word denoted by -e)-s exception(search word denoted by -s)
```

Now the user will have an option to enter multiple exclude words and multiple search words.

Now so far I have achieved that the input format is:

```
file.py test.txt test_mod.txt abc exception".
```

This excludes the word "abc" and search for "exception".

But I don't know how to:

1. Include multiple search word and exclude words
2. How to denote them by -e and -s. I have seen the argparse and the getopt tutorial. But there's no tutorial on this specific topic.

Please can somebody help me by modifying my code or write a new one?

Here's my code as of now:

```
#/Python33

import sys
import os




def main(): #main method

 try:

  f1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')    #takes the first input file in command line
  found = False
  user_input1 = (sys.argv[3])    #takes the word which is to be excluded.
  user_input2 = (sys.argv[4])    #takes the word which is to be included.
  if sys.argv[1] == sys.argv[2]: 
       f1.close()
       sys.exit('\nERROR!!\nThe two file names cannot be the same.') 

  if sys.argv[3] != sys.argv[4]:  

    for line in f1:

        if user_input1 in line or user_input2 in line:

           f2 = open(sys.argv[2], 'a') 

           if user_input1 in line:
              if user_input2 in line:
                   pass

           elif user_input2 in line:
              f2.write(line)
              found = True
              f2.close()


    if not found:
        print("ERROR: The Word couldn't be found.")            



    f1.close()


  if sys.argv[3] == sys.argv[4]: 
         f1.close()
         sys.exit('\nERROR!!\nThe word to be excluded and the word to be included  cannot be the same.') 



 except IOError:
       print('\nIO error or wrong file name.') 
 except IndexError:
       print('\nYou must enter 5 parameters.') #prevents less than 5 inputs which is  mandatory
 except SystemExit as e:                       #Exception handles sys.exit()
       sys.exit(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Thanks man. That really helped me understand the logic. But I'm new to python, so I'm still having some issues.Whenever I run it, it copies the file with the words specified by -s but it's not excluding the words specified by -e. What am I doing wrong? So here's my code now:
    #/Python33

```
#takes a text file, finds a word and writes that line containing that word but not a 2nd word specified by the user. So if both of them are there, that line is not printed

import sys
import os
import argparse



def main(): #main method

 try:

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copies selected lines from files')
  parser.add_argument('input_file')
  parser.add_argument('output_file')
  parser.add_argument('-e',action="append")
  parser.add_argument('-s',action="append")
  args = parser.parse_args('test.txt, test_mod.txt, -e , -s exception'.split())


  user_input1 = (args.e)    #takes the word which is to be excluded.
  user_input2 = (args.s)    #takes the word which is to be included.

  def include_exclude(input_file, output_file, exclusion_list=[], inclusion_list=[]):


      with open(output_file, 'w') as fo:
        with open(input_file, 'r') as fi:
            for line in fi:
                inclusion_words_in_line = map(lambda x: x in line, inclusion_list)
                exclusion_words_in_line = map(lambda x: x in line, exclusion_list)
                if any(inclusion_words_in_line) and not any(exclusion_words_in_line):
                    fo.write(line)    
  if user_input1 != user_input2 : 
         include_exclude('test.txt', 'test_mod.txt', user_input1, user_input2);
         print("hello")

  if user_input1 == user_input2 : 


         sys.exit('\nERROR!!\nThe word to be excluded and the word to be included cannot be the same.') 



 except IOError:
       print('\nIO error or wrong file name.')  
 except IndexError:
       print('\nYou must enter 5 parameters.') 
 except SystemExit as e:                      
       sys.exit(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: I had to cleanup the indentation a bit, but your code works fine for me (both including and excluding). Did you forget to change `parser.parse_args('test...)` back to `parser.parse_args()` and similarly change `test.txt` and `test_mod.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
»»» import argparse

»»» parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='foo baaar')

»»» parser.add_argument('input_file')
Out[3]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='input_file', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

»»» parser.add_argument('output_file')
Out[4]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='output_file', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

»»» parser.add_argument('-e', action="append")
Out[5]: _AppendAction(option_strings=['-e'], dest='e', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

»»» parser.add_argument('-s', action="append")
Out[6]: _AppendAction(option_strings=['-s'], dest='s', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

»»» parser.parse_args('foo1.txt foo2.txt -e abc -e def -s xyz -s pqr'.split())
Out[7]: Namespace(e=['abc', 'def'], input_file='foo1.txt', output_file='foo2.txt', s=['xyz', 'pqr'])
```

If you just call `parser.parse_args()`, it will parse the arguments passed to your script, but the above is handy for testing. Note how multiple search and exclude words are specified using multiple `-s` and `-e` flags. By passing `action="append"` to the `add_argument` method, arguments after `-s` and `-e` are added to a list in the namespace returned by `parser.parse_args`. This should address your questions `1.` and `2.`.

Here's an example of how you can access the values in a nice way:

```
»»» args = parser.parse_args('foo1.txt foo2.txt -e abc -e def -s xyz -s pqr'.split())

»»» args.e
Out[12]: ['abc', 'def']
```

I used the [argparse docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html), especially [the add_argument method doc](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) is very useful.

EDIT: here's one function that does the inclusion/exclusion logic:

```
def include_exclude(input_file, output_file, inclusion_list, exclusion_list=[]):
    with open(output_file, 'w') as fo:
        with open(input_file, 'r') as fi:
            for line in fi:
                inclusion_words_in_line = map(lambda x: x in line, inclusion_list)
                exclusion_words_in_line = map(lambda x: x in line, exclusion_list)
                if any(inclusion_words_in_line) and not any(exclusion_words_in_line):
                    fo.write(line)
```

The `with` statement ensures that the file is properly closed if anything goes wrong (see the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement)). Instead, you could of course use the same open/close code you already have. Indeed, my code doesn't include any error handling, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. In the main `for` loop, I loop over all the lines in the input file. Then, I look at all the words in inclusion_list, and check if they occur in the `line`. The [`map` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is IMHO an elegant way of doing this; it takes (for example) the words in `inclusion_list`, and generates another list by *mapping* each of the items of `inclusion_list` to the function `lambda x: x in line`. The function just returns `True` if it's input (a word from `inclusion_list` appears in the line), so you end up with a list of True/False items. Brief example:

```
»»» line="foo bar"

»»» words=['foo', 'barz']

»»» map(lambda x: x in line, words)
Out[24]: [True, False]
```

Now I apply the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function to check if, well, any of the items in the `inclusion_words_in_line` list are True, and to check if none (`not any`) of the items in exclusion_words_in_line are True. If that's the case, the `line` is appended to the output file. If you wanted to ensure that `all` of the words in `inclusion_list` appear on the line, rather than any (this wasn't clear to me from your problem description), you can use the [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function instead.

Note that you can quite easily solve the above with for loops that loop over the `inclusion_list` and `exclusion_list`s, checking if the items are there, there's no need to use `map` and `any`.

Comment: This code,separates the words denoted by -e and by -s.But my target is to read from a text file and to copy the selected lines into a new file which will also be created.That means the lines contains the words denoted as-s in the command prompt but notdenoted by-e.So suppose(test.txt)contains two lines: 1.This is a file with exception.2.abc exception.When I type in the command prompt:file.py test.txt test_mod.txt -e abc -s exception, a new file will be created named "test_mod.txt"with the line:"This is a file with exception".And I also can enter multiple -e or -s in the prompt.How do I do that

Comment: What `m01` gave you not is the full replacement for your code.  It just replaces the direct access to `sys.argv[n]`.  i.e. replace `sys.argv[1]` with `args.input_file`, `sys.argv[2]` with `args.out_file`, `user_input1=args.e` (except this is now a list of words, not just one).

Comment: I thought you were quite close to having the search bit done. Now that you can get lists of inclusion/exclusion words, you might want to try to change your code a bit to account for that. I'll edit the post to show how to do that, too, in case you get stuck.

Comment: @m01 please help..I have edited my new code but there are some issues I've mentioned.